# DNS host name not resolving for server

Tags: windows-xp, router, dns

I am attempting to host a game server from home on one of my extra computers. I have a cable modem connected to a Netgear router + wireless gateway combo running DD-WRT firmware. From there I have a small switch with my server and other computers connected.

The server is running Windows XP. The game server works fine and both LAN clients and external/remote clients can connect to the game server by entering my IP address directly (internal IP for LAN clients or external WAN IP for remote clients).

I have a DDNS name from `freedns.afriad.org` (`13acres.pwnz.org`) and my router is configured correctly to update the DNS dynamically. I also have a DNS from a friends domain that points to me as well at `13acres.rubequake.com`.

However, I *cannot* connect to my server using the DNS name (either one). I can ping the DNS names and I get a response, so I think it is at least making it to the router (or cable modem?). However the hostname can’t be resolved. Using a DNS check utility on the web reports various errors I don’t know what to do with.

Basically I am at loss for what else I need to do to get the DNS name routed correctly to the server. Do I need to mess with other DNS settings in the router or somehow forward the DNS to the server computer's internal IP address? Are there network adapter settings on the server computer that I need to set (DNS name? Hostname? Hostfiles?).

My network knowledge dries up right about here, so any help to get this working would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to open the ports on your router for whatever game you're trying to play.

Would be best if you assign the server a static IP on the network so the port opening sticks (e.g. 192.168.0.10)

the DNS name (13acres.pwnz.org) still needs to have a port appended to the end, like 13acres.pwnz.org:25565 when trying to access it from outside your network

Comment: Yes - the required ports are open and clients use port 26000 to connect.  Again connecting via ip works. They use 13acres.pwnz.org:25000 to attempt to connect via the DNS name.

Comment: Nslookup times out with both of the servers - so I am assuming that it is not working correctly on the DNS end?  It is odd that I can ping the named DNS and it goes to my ip but nslookup doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your friends DNS 13acres.rubequake.com is not working don't use it. Yours seems to be working at 13acres.pwnz.org.

DNS just takes an IP address and turns it into a name like 13acres.pwnz.org. Nothing more it doesn't do any routing what so ever. 
Test it by opening a command prompt and do a "nslookup 13acres.pwnz.org" if the result is your external IP address then its working.

Comment: Sorry, typo.  It's 13acres.runequake.com (rune not rube).